# npm node app.js different apache

Tags: apache, npm

I was able to start my own RTCMultiConnection in my dedicated hosting.
https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection

The problem I hit is when I want to integrate it in a full php / ajax / jquery website I made. 
A site with login using ajax calls.

because the RTCMultiConnection requires node js and a different port (like https://www.__MyDomain.com:9001/ ),
I thought I could insert it in my site usign a XMLHttpRequest.

**** Problem ; I get a Allow-Control-Allow-Origin error

-- I tried to add it in .htaccess but without success... ;(

-- I went to my regular php.ini and installed mod_headers ; same thing no success ;(

•• I tried curl -I https://__MyDomain.com:9001/
   and "Surprise surprise I get : HTTP/1.1 200 OK......
   but my regular site (without the :9001) have Apache/2.2.31

---

The QUESTION HERE (is related to node and not RTCMultiConnection) ; **WHY does "node server.js" have a different apache ???**

Is it possible to "tell" or "ask" node to use the same apache config that I have ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep running `server.js` on port `9001` and access/use/invoke socket.io/nodejs from your main PHP website. E.g.

```
rtcMultiConnection.socketURL = 'https://yourdomain.com:9001/';
```

Now your PHP pages will successfully use socket.io that is running on port 9001.

You can try this for testing purpose:

```
rtcMultiConnection.socketURL = 'https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443/';
```

**Note:** You can NOT run both nodejs and appache/php on **same port**: 80 or 443. That's why it is suggested to keep running nodejs on-a-separate-port 9001 and access/use socket.io from your PHP pages.

Comment: Thanks ;) !!! before your answer I was thinking doing iframe, but this is much better ;)